# Python - How to check if a Google Spreadsheets was updated

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I needed to check if there was an update to the shared Google Spreadsheets document. I thought of bringing the field "Last edit was made on September 15 by Rob" as a date or as a timestamp in Python and check if the difference was less than a day, but I didn't find anything in the documentation about that.

My code so far:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import gspread
import pandas as pd

def get_gsheet_table(url, sheet_name):

    scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('./credentials/get_sheet_table.json', scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wb = gc.open_by_url(url)
    sheet = wb.worksheet(sheet_name)
    
    #TODO: check if there was an update

    data = sheet.get_all_values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    return df
```

I'm trying to do this way of taking the date out of the document because I didn't want to need to make a backup spreadsheet and compare the two.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about checking it using the method of "Revisions: list" in Drive API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for this.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much for that. I don't know how I didn't find that haha. Thank you one more time

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? It will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) with the link to the documentation, I was able to solve the problem.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

revisions_uri = f'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{wb.id}/revisions'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.get_access_token().access_token}'}
    response = requests.get(revisions_uri, headers=headers).json()
    print(response['revisions'][-1]['modifiedTime'])
```